# How to stop developer preview?

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-630, developer-preview

My Nokia Lumia 630 SS got Developer Preview enabled but due to unavailability of wifi my OS version sticked to 8.10.12400.899. As a result every time i switch on data connection a notification pop up for connecting to wifi. I have tried to uncheck the "Enable Preview for Developers" checkbox in the DP app but with no help. Then I soft reset the phone 5 times but problem persist.
How to completely stop DP app? Even after removing the app same notification pops up.

Comment: Is this duplicate question ??? weird, I ask @Indrek and community. I think is this not a duplicate.

Comment: @Indrek There is no clear answer for my question which you linked.

Comment: Hello @Abhinaba well my answer is not clear then I remove my answer, thanks

Comment: Your last answer was related to me, I contact Microsoft support team & confirmed me that without updating to latest version of pfd i can't get official denim update. Thanks you .

Comment: @Abhinaba The linked question may not have an accepted answer, but the question is essentially the same - how to install Denim on a DP-updated phone -, hence the duplicate.

Comment: @Indrek OP question clearly explain how to stop developer preview. OP not ask how to update nokia denim. you can't say it's duplicate.

Comment: @Skydream The OP asks, quote, "How do I update my DP phone to Lumia Denim?"

Comment: @Indrek I removed the denim update portion,hopes you will not tag it aduplicate one?

Comment: @Indrek Your can't understand OP completely. As per last Abhinaba comment clearly says remove duplication mark.

Comment: @Skydream Please read [this Help Center article](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) for information on how to re-open a closed question.

Comment: @Abhinaba Have you tried unchecking the "Enable Preview for Developers" checkbox in the DP app? As the app itself explains, that will un-enroll you from the preview programme and should stop notifications for preview OS updates.

Comment: Yes,I unchecked the box but problem not solved,notification still appears.

Comment: You'll have to re-flash your device with the Lumia Software Recovery Tool then restore from backup.